# error MSB3073 with Exit code 1 in Visual Stuido 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have done a setup to run few commands in PreBuild Event of VS2010.

```
> pushd $(ProjectDir)..\..\..\..\..\..\adc424cr10\src\common\vcfg python
> .\parseXmlConfig.py --file ..\xml\ADC424CR10_VCFG.xml --input
> CR10-14F022-AD01 python ..\..\..\utils\xmlgen\xmlgen_cli.py --types
> ..\xml\ADC424CR10_VCFG_types.xml --config ..\xml\ADC424CR10_VCFG.xml
> --quiet --force --addr 0x0080000 --bin --output .  powershell -Command "(Get-Content 'ADC424CR10_VCFG_access.h') -notmatch 'stdbool' |
> Set-Content 'ADC424CR10_VCFG_access.h' " popd
```

But i'm facing below compilation error.
    Any possible thoughts what caused this issue?

```
1>PreBuildEvent:
1>  U:\Trailer\sv\projects\adc424cr10\src\common\vcfg\0101.partnumber
1>  Protoc support disabled as protoc compiler cannot be found in PATH
1>EXEC : error : [decimal point found for integer member - truncating]!!
1>  0101.partnumber : writing  16 bytes uncompressed
1>  2001  bytes written to file ADC424CR10_VCFG.bin
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(103,5): error MSB3073: The command "pushd U:\Trailer\sv\projects\base\utils\mts\mv_projects\sv_algo\lib_vcfg\..\..\..\..\..\..\adc424cr10\src\common\vcfg
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(103,5): error MSB3073: python .\parseXmlConfig.py --file ..\xml\ADC424CR10_VCFG.xml --input CR10-14F022-AD01
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(103,5): error MSB3073: python ..\..\..\utils\xmlgen\xmlgen_cli.py --types ..\xml\ADC424CR10_VCFG_types.xml --config ..\xml\ADC424CR10_VCFG.xml --quiet --force --addr 0x0080000 --bin --output .
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(103,5): error MSB3073: powershell -Command "(Get-Content 'ADC424CR10_VCFG_access.h') -notmatch 'stdbool' | Set-Content 'ADC424CR10_VCFG_access.h' "
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(103,5): error MSB3073: popd
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(103,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code -1.
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

Also i found that all the commands ran successfully(I mean intended work has been done) but its just that source code has not been compiled due to preBuild event failure

Comment: Does the command run in a Visual Studio command prompt?

Comment: @user1810087 i just tried running in Visual Studio Command prompt, commands didn't report any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xmlgen_cli.py had issues with one of the parameter in the inputs which lead to an error

> EXEC : error : [decimal point found for integer member - truncating]!!

In PreBuild event if any of the commands raise an exception/error VS studio probably complains with below exit code

> VCEnd" exited with code -1.

By fixing the raised exception this issue has been resolved.